# select item in NavigationView with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have this piece of code

```
 private void setupDrawerLayout() {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            final int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();

            switch (itemId) {
                case R.id.drawer_my_mixes:
                    replaceFragment(MyMixesFragment.newInstance());
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                   and so on...
```

I want to make espresso to click `R.id.drawer_settings` which will basically open a fragment called SettingsFragment. How do I do this? I tried this with no success

```
private ViewInteraction navigateToSettings(){
    openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext());
    return onView(withText("Settings")).perform(click());

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way would be to use the onData function of Espresso.

`onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(NavigationMenuItem.class)), ... )).perform(click());`

But NavigationMenuItem isn't accessible since it is a private nested class.

An issue is pending https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187701 to find a solution on it. Go add a star to it ;-)

Comment: In espresso 2 you can use `onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).perform(DrawerActions.open());`. More info look [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32854962/1332549)

Answer (score 1):

openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu() does not open NavigationView.

For me the following works:

```
//Open NavigationView
Matcher<View> isImageButton = withClassName(is(ImageButton.class.getName()));
Matcher<View> isInToolbar = isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.toolbar));
onView(allOf(isInToolbar, isImageButton)).perform(click());

//Click on item in NavigationView
onView(withText(R.string.logout)).perform(click());
```

This solution works for me temporarily until a better solution like suggested by user40797 is working...

Answer (score 0):

### How to select an item in the NavigationView.

**In your package utils:**

```
public class NavigationViewTestHelper {

    public static Matcher<View> childAtPosition(
            final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int position) {

        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("Child at position " + position + " in parent ");
                parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
                return parent instanceof ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                        && view.equals(((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(position));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**In your test after opening your NavigationView.**

```
ViewInteraction navigationMenuItemView = onView(
                allOf(childAtPosition(
                        allOf(withId(R.id.design_navigation_view),
                                childAtPosition(
                                        withId(R.id.*your_navigation_view_id*),
                                        0)),
                        1), // Position of the element in the Navigation view.
                        isDisplayed()));

navigationMenuItemView.perform(click());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [MiguelHincapieC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1332549/miguelhincapiec) response, This is what worked for me:

```
onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).perform(DrawerActions.open());
```

Hope it helps :).