# openDrawer from espresso contrib is deprecated

Tags: android, open-source, automated-tests, android-testing, android-espresso

Espresso contrib (`com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1`) openDrawer method is deprecated

then how should I open a drawer?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here's an example on how to use the new `open` and `close` methods:

`onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).perform(DrawerActions.open());`

`onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).perform(DrawerActions.close());`

Comment: I have the following problem, after using these lines to open the drawer, the next operation, which performs a click on the item inside the drawer, fails because the drawer closes instantly. What could cause a close drawer when there is no other operation after that?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for `openDrawer` suggests using the `open` method with the correct resource id and perform `ViewAction`.

> Use open() with perform after matching a view. This method will be
>   removed in the next release.

---

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/DrawerActions.html#open(int)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out! This will get the menu from toolbar, and press a click on him

```
onView(allOf(withContentDescription("Menu"),
             withParent(withId(R.id.toolbar)),
             isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```